# Android optional word boundary regex

Tags: android, regex, patternsyntaxexception

I'm having trouble with a regular expression when targeting the Android platform 2.2.3.

The following regular expression works when targeting the Java VM on my desktop and the regular expression is also working on a .NET application too.

```
Pattern.compile("\\b?")
```

But when I target my phone I get a PatternSyntaxException. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know motivation of the error... but this is an optional (and however zero length) word boundary... what are you going to match after all??

Comment: Well it's a rather complicated regex from a different project. But I don't see why an optional word boundary should be invalid pattern syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that this does throw a `PatternSyntaxException` when running in the Android emulator, but not in a regular Java application.  I can't see why that would be the case, other than the fact that regular expression implementation used in Android is different than in the normal Java SDK.  From the [Pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Android Developers page:

> The regular expression implementation used in Android is provided by ICU. The notation for the regular expressions is mostly a superset of those used in other Java language implementations. This means that existing applications will normally work as expected, but in rare cases Android may accept a regular expression that is not accepted by other implementations.

As a work-around, I did discover that you can get around the exception by enclosing the word boundary assertion in a non-capturing group.

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\b)?");
```

(A capturing group works as well, but I doubt you need it.)

I suggest you [report this as a bug](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) to see if you can get an official response.  (I already searched, and it doesn't appear to be reported yet.)

Comment: But be aware that it's a bug only in the sense that Android rejects some regexes that the reference implementation accepts.  It makes absolutely no sense to include a zero-width assertion and then make it optional.  You're saying, *this condition must hold true, but it's okay if it doesn't.*  By rejecting it, compiler is alerting you to what is either a typo or a failure of understanding on the author's part.

Comment: @AlanMoore I was trying to imagine what the rest of the OP's regex might look like to need an optional word boundary, but I think you're right.  It doesn't make sense.  The way you make a word boundary optional is to just not include it in the regex at all.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Agreed. I don't think it does make sense. I'm not the author of the original regex. Perhaps I misunderstood their usage of '?' could be part of a capture group possibly. Anyway, I've decided to just implement the same solution my way.